# General-purpose clear function for stack<ItemType>

Tags: c++

Is there a way to write a general-purpose function to clear any stack in C++ with any given item type? I am currently writing a program that uses a string stack and an integer stack but I cannot figure out how to pass the stack as a parameter that decides during runtime which data it contains and how to delete it. My idea was:

```
void clearStack(stack &s) {
    while(!s.empty())
        s.pop();
}
```

However, this states that `argument list for class template "std::stack" is missing`. Does C++ have a way to pass in a stack as a parameter without the need for the value-type?

*Note: this is just for practice. After looking around I learned that `vector::clear` would work great for runtime but I wanted to see if something similar was possible with C++ stacks.

Comment: Make the function a template as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can template your function with the same argument as the stack you pass in e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
void clearStack(std::stack<T>& s) {
    while (!s.empty()){
        s.pop();
    }
}
```

You then don't need to explicitly specify the template argument, the compiler can infer it from the stack type:

```
std::stack<int> s;
clearStack(s);        // Automatically identifies T as int
```